# how to use nested lookup query?

Tags: typescript, database, mongodb, nosql, typegoose

I have two collections "new_users" and "workspaces". I am trying to do a lookup query but it gives only empty array in the expected field.

My 'new_users' collection:

```
export class UserEntity {
    @Prop({ required: false, type: Types.ObjectId, default: () => new ObjectId() })
    _id?: Types.ObjectId;

    @Expose()
    @Prop({ default: '', trim: true, text: true })
    firstName: string;

    @Expose()
    @Prop({ default: '', trim: true, text: true })
    lastName: string;
}
```

My "workspaces" collection:

```
export class WorkspaceUsers {
    @Expose()
    @Prop({ type: () => [WorkspaceUserGroup] })
    groups: WorkspaceUserGroup[];

    @Expose()
    @Prop({ required: true, type: String, enum: WorkspaceRoleEnum })
    workSpaceRole: WorkspaceRoleEnum;

    @Expose()
    @Prop({ required: true, type: String, ref: () => UserEntity })
    userID: string;
}

export class WorkspaceEntity {

    @Prop({ required: false, type: Types.ObjectId, default: () => new ObjectId() })
    _id?: Types.ObjectId;
    
    @Expose()
    @IsString()
    @IsDefined()
    @Prop({ required: true, trim: true })
    name: string;
    

    @Expose()
    @IsOptional()
    @IsArray()
    @ValidateNested({ each: true })
    @Type(() => WorkspaceUsers)
    @Prop({ required: false, type: () => [WorkspaceUsers], default: [] })
    users: WorkspaceUsers[];
}
```

Now I want to run a lookup query in my workspaces model like this:

```
    const aggregationQuery: PipelineStage[] = [];

    aggregationQuery.push({
        $unwind: '$users',
    });

    aggregationQuery.push({
        $lookup: {
            from: 'new_users',
            localField: 'users.userID',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'userData',
        },
    });
```

It is returning an empty array in userData field. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: hmm i couldnt replicate https://mongoplayground.net/p/vFkPHP6akRb

Comment: i think i see userID is string in WorkspaceUsers but _id is object id in UserEntity . you have to convert to either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to match a string and an object id in the lookup stage so it returns an empty array as a result

you can either change your model so that `userID` is `Types.ObjectId` or you can manage that in the aggregation stage as well. An example is to convert the string field to object id field in a pipeline stage

for example you can use `$addFields` to convert the string field to object id field before doing the lookup

```js
db.workspaces.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$users"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "users.userID": {
        $toObjectId: "$users.userID"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "new_users",
      localField: "users.userID",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "userData"
    }
  }
])
```

[sample playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bIO8nJpo3UV)

Comment: thanks a lot. I am marking it as accepted as it worked for me.